# Gradle Build Fail: Unable to find method org.gradle.tooling.model.gradle.GradleBuild.getIncludedBuilds

Tags: android, react-native

I have a question.

I have React Native codebase that I was recently tasked to work on.

It is giving me the following error whenever I try to build the app from inside the 
Android Studio.

Versions:
Android Studio - version 3.0.
React-native version - 0.56.0

Here's my gradle-wrapper.properties.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Here's the app's build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Error:Unable to find method 'org.gradle.tooling.model.gradle.GradleBuild.getIncludedBuilds()Lorg/gradle/tooling/model/DomainObjectSet;'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
* Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
* The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
* Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
* Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Does anyone know where I can start debugging?